# cmake does not recognise flags in debug mode

Tags: gcc, cmake

I have this part of cmake code:

```
set(MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS "-ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra")
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_compile_options(main PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>")
```

I run this cmake with flag which set mode to debug:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

But output prints an error:

```
gcc/x86_64/7.3.0a/bin/c++    -g   "-ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra" -o 
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -c main.cpp
c++: error: unrecognized debug output level ‘3 -Wall -Wextra’
```

Could some of you point a mistake in this code?
Regards,

Comment: when i use this: set(MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS ${COMPILE_OPTIONS} -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra) then output is vaild, but flag "g" is not set

Comment: Use one *generator expression* per compile option. This is how generator expressions works: they are processed at build stage, so arguments separating should already be done.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Could you shed some light on this proposal?

Comment: Em? You need to pass options separately, each one with its own generator expression: `$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-ggdb3> $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-Wall> ...`

Comment: bu what if i want set the same variables for multi target's? Option with set variable which contains string with variables is in my opinion the one.

Comment: You may use `for` cycle for wrap every option into config-dependent generator expression. You may even store a generator expression or a list of them into the variable, and use this variable later.